# ADO.NET Data service does not show the available entity's when deployed in II6

Tags: wcf, rest, odata, wcf-data-services, wcf-ria-services

I am using WCF OData service (.Net 3.5) to expose a DB table as a OData service. When I run the service in my local, I could see the avaialble contexts as shown below. (The student and Comapny context)

[image]

But when I deploy the same in IIS 6.0 (Server 2003), the service does not show the avalaible contexts. Please advice. Thanks in advance.

[image]

I also found that the method InitializeService is not getting triggered at all. Any Clue. ?

```
public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
{
    string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Log"];
            File.AppendAllText(path, string.Format("{0} : Started", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")));

    config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
    config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
    config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = System.Data.Services.Common.DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
}
```

Following is my config Http Handler section.

```
<httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" />
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
```

Comment: Sounds like an IIS handler issue, although the fact that the service actually renders an empty feed throws the theory a little off balance. Still, could you post the `/configuration/system.webServer/handlers` section in your Web.config file and/or any difference between these sections in the applicationHost.config files of the two servers (local and IIS6)? As a workaround that might also shed some light on the issue, you could try hosting it in an ASP.NET application by adding a `System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceRoute` to the application's RouteTable (which should call InitializeService).

Comment: @tne Thanks for your reply. I have updated the question with the httpHandler. Also there is no difference between my local and IIS copy of the http handler. Will also try to do the workaround.

Comment: OK, these shouldn't conflict with the `svc-*` handlers. I'm a little out of ideas right now, let us know if using `ServiceRoute` instead of the IIS handler helps by any chance. Also, just throwing it out there for good measure: are you 100% sure that the code in `InitializeService` doesn't run? If it fails (for example an I/O exception with the log instruction) you may only see the exception in your server logs, but the service could still be running on defaults (not sure about that behavior).

Comment: @tne While digging more, I found that, it works for me if I use IDataServiceConfiguration instaed of DataServiceConfiguration as a parameter for the method InitializeService. But I need to use DataServiceConfiguration to set the MaxProtocolVersion to DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2; Any idea ?

Comment: I guess "ADO.NET Data Services Update for .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 for Windows Server 2003" is not installed in the server. Will install the service pack and check..

Comment: I think OData 3 support was introduced in WCF-DS 5, and that WCF-DS 5 targets .NET 4.  This means you might be stuck to OData 2.  You should get a hard confirmation on that, I'm not absolutely certain.

Comment: @tne : I am still stuck with this. The Ado.Net Data services V1 works for me. But V2 does't work on the windows 2003 server. Any advice?

Comment: Sorry, I really only have experience with V3 on Server 2012 and .NET 4.5. My advice would be to edit your question or post a new question by mentioning your version requirements explicitly in the title; you'll hopefully get the attention of people who can actually test things out in the same environment as you. You may also try the [official boards](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=adodotnetdataservices) if you haven't already.